# How does a bat have +0 modifier to attack?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, attack, proficiency

I am quite new to playing DND and I'm struggling to understand how a bat has +0 to attack. I'm clearly missing something, but as per my calculations:

A [bat](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/bat) has a strength of 2 (-4 Modifier).
This is countered by a +2 of proficiency.

Looking at the bite attack (emphasis mine):

> Bite. Melee Weapon Attack: **+0 to hit,** reach 5 ft., one creature. Hit: (1d1) piercing damage.

How is this calculated to +0? Should this not be -2?

Comment: Hello and welcome! You can take the [tour] to learn a bit more about how this site works. For future reference, the reason the dungeons-and-dragons tag was removed from your question is because it is used for D&D questions across editions (no big deal though don't worry). Thank you for participating and happy gaming!

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by " This is countered by a +2 of proficiency"? I know this question is now answered, but it seems to me that a bat's proficiency is not knowable from its stats (since it doesn't seem to be proficient in any skills or saving throws).

Comment: @Gandalfmeansme: There's a table of "Proficiency Bonus by Challenge Rating" in the intro to the Monster Manual and the corresponding section of the basic rules: https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/monsters#ProficiencyBonusbyChallengeRating

Comment: The rules you are using are written for player characters only. They do not apply to NPCs as anything more than vague guidelines

Answer (score 36, accepted):

## I don't think there is a formula that will give us that +0.

The bat is a very weak creature, with a CR 0. Most likely, the D&D designers just didn't want him to have a negative attack modifier, so they set it at 0, despite having -4 STR and +2 DEX.

- If the attack was strength-based, the bat would need a +4 Proficiency (a bit high for a CR0 creature).
- If it were Dexterity-based, the bat would have -2 Proficiency (negative proficiency?).

**It was a balance decision.** The bat also does 1-damage with that attack, which is not derived from any formula. An unarmed strike is usually 1+STR, and a natural attack 1d4+STR, so both would deal non-positive damage.

From the DMG, on Creating Monsters (credit to [Sdjz](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/33707/sdjz)):

> You can start with the monster's expected Challenge Rating table to determine an appropriate attack bonus for all the monster's attacks, regardless of its ability scores. [...] Feel free to adjust the attack bonus as you see fit to match whatever concept you have in mind.

Also, AFAIK, there aren't monsters with negative attack modifiers, are there?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88436/discussion-on-answer-by-bluemoon93-how-does-a-bat-have-0-modifier-to-attack).